# Nodesets Length

Tags: xml, xslt, nodesets

In XLST how would you find out the length of a node-set?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="length" select="count(nodeset)"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

there is no need to put that into a

```
<xsl:variable name="length" select="count(nodes/node)"/>
```

though... you can just print it out as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(nodes/node)"/>
```

or use it in a if-clause as follows:

```
<xsl:if test="count(comments/comment) > '0'">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="comments/comment"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: You'll want to make that > into a &gt; though!

Answer (score 4):

Generally in XSLT things aren't referred to as `Arrays`, since there is really no such thing in XSLT. The technical term is either `nodesets` (made up of zero or more nodes) or in XSLT 2.0 `sequences`.